# How can I figure out which Sidekiq jobs are taking up so much memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, memory-management, sidekiq

I am running 4 Sidekiq processes on an R3 Large AWS VM, and a total of 100 sidekiq jobs. An R3 has 15.25 GB RAM assigned to it, and 2 CPUs.

Jobs consistently fail due to extremely heavy swapping. The worst I've ever seen. I have just decided to shut down the production background environment while I bring up a bigger VM.

I don't want to keep doing this though. I need to do the hard work to find out where I can optimize my jobs. I am absolutely certain that there are only 1 or 2 kinds of jobs that are causing me these headaches. I just don't know how to find them.

How can I see which processes are causing the biggest problems with memory among my Sidekiq jobs?

Comment: are you able to log into the aws instance and use `htop`?

Comment: You should use a third-party library to track the performance of your workers, like [New Relic](http://newrelic.com). New Relic integrates with Sidekiq and includes a "Background jobs report" feature, a thread profiler, and tracks all your transactions.